# In SQL, how can I find and return the value nearest in time to a selected value?

Tags: sql, datetime, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking at data returned from a streaming platform and it currently looks something like this:

| user_id | date_time | user_action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xxx | 2021-05-22 20:28:30.000 | click : genre RAP |
| xxx | 2021-05-22 20:28:38.000 | plays_song: SONG-A |
| xxx | 2021-05-22 20:29:05.000 | time_listened: 3 |
| xxx | 2021-05-22 20:29:09.000 | click : genre COUNTRY |
| xxx | 2021-05-22 20:29:15.000 | plays_song: SONG-B |
| xxx | 2021-05-22 21:54:12.000 | time_listened: 4 |

I want to be able to attribute the amount of time to the correct genre for each user. So in this example user "xxx" listened to two songs one in the RAP genre and one in the COUNTRY genre. In order to know what genre each song is in you would need to look at the closest click that happened before the song play occurred and in order to get the time you would need the look at the closest time_listened that happened after the song play.

The ideal result would be :

| user_id | user_action | genre | time_spent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxx | plays_song: song a | click : genre rap | time_listened: 3 |
| xxx | plays_song: song b | click : genre country | time_listened: 4 |

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Don't understand your requirement; you don't give any context, explain clearly in your question exactly how you arrive at your desired results.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Where is your code, what have you tried.

Comment: I have no idea where to start with this so I haven't tried anything.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can assign a group to the rows by counting the "clicks" up to each row.  Then aggregate:

```
select userid,
       max(case when user_action like 'click:%' then user_action end) as click_action,
       max(case when user_action like 'plays_song:%' then user_action end) as plays_song_action,
       max(case when user_action like 'click:%' then datetime end) as click_datetime,
       max(case when user_action like 'plays_song:%' then datetime end) as plays_song_datetime
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when user_action like 'click:%' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by userid order by datetime) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by userid, grp;
```

Date/time functions are notoriously database-dependent.  So this returns the two date/time values.  You can calculate the difference however is appropriate in your database.